# Update the variable value inside the runnable class

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java. I am having trouble updating variables in the TimerRunnable class from the Main class. Is this possible to do?

This is my Main.java

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerRunnable tr = new TimerRunnable(5);
        Thread thread = new Thread(tr);

        thread.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch(Exception ignored) {}

        System.out.println("main");
        tr.resetTimer(true);
    }
}
```

TimerRunnable.java :

```
import java.lang.Thread;

public class TimerRunnable implements Runnable {
    public boolean reset = false;
    private int sec;

    public TimerRunnable(int sec) {
        this.sec = sec;
    }

    public synchronized void resetTimer(boolean v) {
        this.reset = v;
    }

    private synchronized boolean checkResetTimer() {
        return this.reset;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = this.sec;

        while(i>=0) {
            if(this.checkResetTimer()) {
                i=sec;
                System.out.println(i);
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " = " + i + "/" + sec);
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000L);
            } catch(Exception e) {}

            if(this.checkResetTimer()) {
                resetTimer(false);
            }

            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[me@laptop java]$ java Main
Thread-0 = 5/5
Thread-0 = 4/5
main
Thread-0 = 3/5
Thread-0 = 2/5
Thread-0 = 1/5
Thread-0 = 0/5
```

Expected output :

```
[me@laptop java]$ java Main
Thread-0 = 5/5
Thread-0 = 4/5
main
Thread-0 = 5/5
Thread-0 = 4/5
Thread-0 = 3/5
Thread-0 = 2/5
Thread-0 = 1/5
Thread-0 = 0/5
```

My goal in updating variables in the TimerRunnable class is so that the countdown timer can return to its original value.

Comment: you are running into the second `checkResetTimer` check and you reset the timer to `false` without resetting seconds?

Comment: I think its done in the first ``checkResetTimer`` check?

Comment: yeah but the problem is that if your call from main Thread is executed during the sleep of your TimerThread then you miss a timer reset.

Comment: Yes, I got it..

Comment: Thankyou pero_hero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your uodating the reset while your runner is sleeping, and then it always clears the reset and continues. To fix, first update the first check for reset in your runner

```
        if(this.checkResetTimer()) {
            i=sec;
            System.out.println(i);
            resetTimer(false);
        }
```

Then get rid of the second check

```
        // if(this.checkResetTimer()) {
        //     resetTimer(false);
        // }
```

Comment: @Mr.Openk please check the checkmark next to my answer to mark this question answered

Comment: Ok @ControlAltDel